# OS specific tests with ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, operating-system, tdd

I've the following Rakefile

```
require 'bundler/gem_tasks'
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |task|
  task.libs << %w(test lib)
  task.pattern = 'test/**/*_test.rb'
end

task default: :test
```

And test are defined with minitest:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'certmanager'

class CertificateTest < Minitest::Test
  context 'settings' do
    should 'retrieve settings' do
      assert_equal 'test123', Certmanager::Settings.key_passphrase
    end
  end
end
```

Now there is also some OS specific code like `FileUtils.ln_s` on Linux and `FileUtils.cp` on Windows. This code requires different tests. In this case e.g. `assert_equal filepath, File.readlink(linkpath)` (Linux) vs. `assert File.exist?(filepath)` (windows)

What is the best practice to differentiate between OS Types?
Do I have t write the tests in a way that Linux can test windows specific code and vice versa?
Is it possible to differentiate "inline" in an test?
Is it necessary to have two different testsets and decide in the Rakefile which set needs to be executed? Is it even possible int the Rakefile?

Comment: Yes, it works, whereas `File.readlink` and `FileUtils.ln_s` won't work on Windows (NotImplemented Exception). Therefore you've to use something different on Windows. In my case `FileUtils.cp`. Since `FileUtils.cp` and `FileUtils.ln_s` have different return values you'll have to use different tests. In addition it's just an example. There are different cases. Another one could be an default config path. On Linux e.g. `/etc/certmanager` and on Windows `C:/User/.../AppData/.../certmanager`. Again I would say you need two different tests dependent on the OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to run every test regardless of the current OS, i wrote a module `TestHelper`. This module contains severall methods to

- pretend a windows or posix environment for the test
- setup stubs for methods that are not implemented (or work in a different way) on the actual OS - currently I've only found those methods on windows
- check if the actual OS is windows or not (if it is necessary to know)

In the test it is possible to simply use `TestHelper.setup_windows_env` or `TestHelper.setup_posix_env` whenever it has to be OS specific.

```
require 'rbconfig'
require 'fileutils'
module TestHelper
  extend self

  def setup_windows_env
    is_windows?
    RbConfig::CONFIG.stubs(:[]).with('host_os').returns('windows')
    ENV.stubs(:[]).with('OS').returns('Windows_NT')
  end

  def setup_stubs_for_windows_in_posix_env
    class << FileUtils
      def ln_s(src, dest, options = {})
        File.open(dest, 'w') { |file| file.write src }
        return 0
      end
    end

    class << File
      def readlink(file_name)
        return File.read(file_name)
      end
    end
  end

  def setup_posix_env
    setup_stubs_for_windows_in_posix_env if is_windows?
    RbConfig::CONFIG.stubs(:[]).with('host_os').returns('darwin')
    ENV.stubs(:[]).with('OS').returns('OSX')
  end

  def is_windows?
    @is_windows ||= ApplicationToTest::Util::OS.is_windows?
  end
end
```

For completeness `ApplicationToTest::Util::OS.is_windows?`:

```
require 'rbconfig'
module ApplicationToTest
  module Util
    module OS
      def self.is_windows?
        begin
          env_os = ENV['OS']
        rescue NameError
          return false
        end
        if RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /^mingw2$|^mingw$|^mswin$|^windows$/
            true
        elsif env_os  == 'Windows_NT'
            true
        else
            false
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```